# PHP SQL, getting data from 2 tables, and not getting right output

Tags: php, mysql

## Databases

Candidates DB - Kandidater

```
(`id`, `name`, `department_id`) VALUES
(7, 'Kandidat 1', 0),
(8, 'Kandidat 2', 0),
(9, 'Kandidat 3', 0),
(10, 'Clarissa F. Andersen', 5000),
(11, 'Sandra Flammild', 5000),
(12, 'Amina Nielsen', 5000),
(13, 'Lise Lundin', 5000),
(14, 'Katrine Skovsgaard', 5000),
(15, 'Helle Lieesol Haugaard', 5000),
(16, 'Alicia Macaulau', 5000),
(17, 'Mark Mikel Thygesen', 5000),
(18, 'Michelle MÃ¸ller', 5000),
(19, 'Nadia Chaker', 5000),
```

Week Schedule DB - Ugeplan

```
    (`ID`, `K_ID`, `man_k`, `tir_k`, `ons_k`, `tor_k`, 
    `fre_k`, `man_g`, `tir_g`, `ons_g`, `tor_g`, `fre_g`, 
    `man_s`, `tir_s`, `ons_s`, `tor_s`, `fre_s`, `DM`, `DT`, 
    `DON`, `DTO`, `DF`, `uge`) 
VALUES (2, 7, '09:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '12:00:00', 
        '00:00:00', '12:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '16:00:00', 
        '00:00:00', '', 'Fri', 'Fri', '', 'Syg', '19-06-2017', 
        '20-06-2017', '21-06-2017', '', 'Syg', 25),
       (3, 7, '09:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '12:00:00', 
        '00:00:00', '12:00:00', '00:00:00', '00:00:00', '16:00:00',       
        '00:00:00', '', 'Fri', 'Fri', '', 'Syg', '19-06-2017', 
        '20-06-2017', '21-06-2017', '', '23-06-2017', 25)
```

*Explanation:*

- K_ID - Candidate ID
- man_k - Monday arriving
- tir_k - Tuesday arriving
- ons_k - Wednesday arriving
- tor_k - Thursday arriving
- fre_k - Friday arriving
- man_g - Monday leaving
- tir_g - Tuesday leaving
- ons_g - Wednesday leaving
- tor_g - Thursday leaving
- fre_g - Friday leaving
- man_s - Monday Status
- tir_s - Tuesday Status
- ons_s - Wednesday Status
- tor_s - Thursday Status
- fre_s - Friday Status
- DM - Date monday
- DT - Date Tuesday
- DON - Date Wednesday
- DTO - Date Thursday
- DF - Date Friday
- uge - Week number

## The Code

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['city'])){
    $by = $_GET['city'];
    $dato = date('d/m/Y');

    $idag = date("D");
    $currentweek = date("W");
    //Setting the right mysql table variables
    $komme = ''; 

    if($idag == Mon){$komme = "man_k"; $datoen = 'DM';}
    else
    if($idag == Tue){$komme = "tir_t"; $datoen = 'DT';}
    else
    if($idag == Wed){$komme = "ons_k"; $datoen = 'DON';}
    else
    if($idag == Thu){$komme = "tor_k"; $datoen = 'DTO';}
    else
    if($idag == Fri){$komme = "fre_k"; $datoen = 'DF';}

    $connection = new mysqli('host', 'username', 'password', 'DB')
    or die ('Cannot connect to db');
?>

<div style="float: left; width: 200px; min-height: 120px; border: 1px solid black;">
<h3>Kandidater i dag</h3>
<?php
    //Getting list off candidates to the preselected department
    $results = $connection->query("select * from kandidater where afdeling_id = $by");

    while ($rows = $results->fetch_assoc()) {

        $id = $rows['id'];
        $person = $rows['navn'];
        //Checking if they are planned to arrive today
        $sql = "select $komme from ugeplan where K_ID ='$id' and $datoen = '$dato'";
        $result = $connection->query($sql);

        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $vis = $row[$komme];
        if($vis == '00:00:00'){}else{
        echo $person . "<br/>";
    }
}
?>
</div>
<?php 
} 
?>
```

## The system

I know this is some bad piece of code, but i can clean it up later, i just need to figure out what i am doing wrong.

The point of this is i am build a website to register arrival, and departure at work. 
Every candidate should be able to check in/out etc.. This is already working, and out being tested.

On the same screen, the assigned leader want to be able, quickly seeing who is planned to arrive today, and then look out for the person, or call them. 
Also in case of an emergency, they want to be able to check is everybody is accounted for, easily by looking at the system.

Comment: you forgot to explain what your problem is! _"and not getting right output
"_ is a bit vague...

Comment: First of all I suggest you to read those articles: http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php and http://www.wikihow.com/Prevent-SQL-Injection-in-PHP

Comment: Do you really have a column in your database holding a date in the format `d/m/Y`? So not a proper MySQL DATE type column? _Not good practice_

Comment: In your place I would rewrite the database structure to allow multiple events per day, if you need them, or multiple events per week, month. Have a look at Database normalization. Probably this vide will give you some good hints https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JbjS7iujCbI

Comment: As i started saying, i know this is bad code. 
And it will properly be rewritten, when i am done with the biggest parts, maybe more work, but thats fine with me. 

The problem is that i am not getting the values that i was hoping for. 

What i need it to show is the names, of the people who are scheduled to arrive that given day. 
I have a people DB, a schedule DB, and a department DB. 

I want to be able to load a location specific page, eg. index.php?department=xxx, and from that the code should show me who should be arriving today, from looking at the schedule DB.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this line at the begining of your PHP:

```
$dato = date('d-m-Y');
```

because you had a 'd/m/Y' date format for your $dato and a 'd-m-Y' format in your Week Schedule DB - Ugeplan table.
Anyways, in your DB you should use the DATE format instead of a varchar to hold your dates columns